# Git Repository on private server

Tags: eclipse, git

I need to create a git repository on a private server using Eclipse and Git plug in on Eclipse.
I created a new C project "Test_Git", then "Team", "Share" etc..and put all the data for the server location.

Eclipse gave me this error:
"org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException: Cannot enter /home/Test_eclipse/objects: No such file"

I want to clone the repo on Eclipse on the remote server in /home/Test_eclipse

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: How do you access the remote server? Via the file system? Do both Git repositories exist? Make sure, first to create the server repository as bare Git repository and then the second repository by cloning it.

Comment: Ok, maybe this is the problem. I did not create a Git repository on the server.
I access to it via sftp.
How can I create the Git repository on the server? The server runs Ubuntu.

Thanks

Comment: I have not yet worked with Git via ftp/sftp, but I assume that creating a bare Git repository (e. g. via Eclipse) and manually transferring the `.git` folder to the server should do it.

Comment: Tried to do this, now Eclipse "sees" the folder, but if I push the folder I did not see anything on the server side..

Comment: Yes, that is correct, because it is a bare repository on the server without a _Working Tree_ (= no files outside of the `.git` subfolder). Only locally, you have to check out a branch (e. g. the `master` branch) to work with.

Comment: I tried to push the master branch, everything seems to work but on the Eclipse error log I got:

"Cannot parse Git URI-ish: The uri was empty or null"

Comment: I don't know if the error message can be ignored. Clone the repository to a second local repository to see if everything worked.